# Progressbar is fill when it is one press for python customtkitner porgressbar

Tags: python, canvas, customtkinter

```
# Create a progress bar
progress_var = DoubleVar()
#progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(canvas,variable=progress_var, length=400,mode='determinate')
progressbar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(back,variable= progress_var, orientation="horizontal", mode='determinate')
canvas.create_window(250, 650, anchor="center", window=progressbar)

# Update the progress bar
progress_var.set(len(exercises_shown) / len(exercises) * 100)
```

The porgress should be updating(slowing fill up) as I click on the button not like fill up instanly. This code has canvas as well.